# Is it possible to get the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (amplitudes) of a qubit in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-state, qiskit, measurement, state-tomography

Is it possible to get the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (amplitudes) of a qubit in Qiskit, i.e. not only probabilities after measurement but complete quantum state?

Comment: I think it is possible to get them only on simulator. On real quantum computer you need employ so-called quantum tomography to "scan" the state.

Comment: @MartinVesely thank you very much, indeed helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using the `statevector_simulator` provided with Qiskit Aer. It will return the statevector that describes the quantum state at the end of your circuit. It can be used in the same way as the `qasm_simulator`, only your circuit shouldn't have measurement gates at the end. There is more information about this simulator in [this tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/8fb0e08bbace67518e5074e6734ecbd4f75d0d75/qiskit/advanced/aer/1_aer_provider.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you very, indeed helpful.